# Allow access on a page to just only a specific member

Tags: membership, content-restriction

I am trying to create a membership site on WP where each members will have access to only specific pages created for them. I mean just a member is allowed to view content on a page while that page is restricted to others. I just to grant on a member access to a page. I don't know if this is possible with the help any plugin

Answer (score 1):

The same concept as Dominic's (no need of a members plugin) but expanded to use a Meta Box, visible only for Admins, with a dropdown list with all the users (with exceptions).

Code borrowed and adapted [from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/33834/12615). Put in `functions.php`:

```
// List Users
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_33725_users_meta_init' );
// Save Meta Details
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_33725_save_userlist' );

function wpse_33725_users_meta_init()
{
    if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        add_meta_box( 'users-meta', 'Authorized User', 'wpse_33725_users_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'high' );
}

function wpse_33725_users_meta_box()
{
    global $post;
    $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $users = $custom["users"][0];

    // prepare arguments
    $user_args  = array(
        // exclude users from the list using an array of ID's
        'exclude' => array(1),
        // order results by display_name
        'orderby' => 'display_name'
    );
    // Create the WP_User_Query object
    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($user_args);
    // Get the results
    $authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();
    // Check for results
    if ( !empty($authors) )
    {
        // Name is your custom field key
        echo "<select name='users'>";
        echo '<option value=0>All</option>';
        // loop trough each author
        foreach ( $authors as $author )
        {
            $author_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'users', true );
            $author_selected = ( $author_id == $author->ID ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo '<option value='.$author->ID.' '.$author_selected.'>'.$author->user_nicename.'</option>';
        }
            echo "</select>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'No authors found';
    }
}


function wpse_33725_save_userlist()
{
    global $post;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
    {
        return $post->ID;
    }

    update_post_meta( $post->ID, "users", $_POST["users"] );
}
```

For checking permissions, this works *outside* the loop in `page.php`:

```
$the_user = get_post_meta( $wp_query->post->ID, 'users', true );

if( '0' == $the_user || empty( $the_user ) ) 
{
    echo "this is a public page";
} 
else 
{
    if( get_current_user_id() == $the_user ) 
        echo "this page is for you";
    else 
    { // NOTHING TO SEE, GO TO FRONT PAGE
        wp_redirect('/');
        header("Status: 302");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend checking out plugins such as paid memberships pro (free), Premise Landing Pages (paid) and restrict content pro (paid). These all could solve your problem.

Comment: Please at least provide links to the plugins you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the IDs of allowed users to a custom field on certain pages. Then use `get_current_user_id()` and see if it's a match before showing the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can check **current user id** at the beginning of the page by **get_current_user_id()** function or you can check more -https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/ and apply condition accordingly.